# how to find the actual length or coordinates of the xlabel in matlab

Tags: matlab, text, plot, label

I am using the following code to find the position of the xlabel in a figure of matlab.

```
xlabel('X');
get(get(gca,'XLabel'),'Position');
```

which gives me some coordinates (0.4981   -0.0669    1.0001). I think that coordinate is just the position of the top-left point of the label. So how do I found the bound for the label if I know the fontsize only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Text objects have an ["Extent"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html#zmw57dd0e406428) property:

> **Extent**
>
> Position and size of text. A four-element vector that defines the size
>   and position of the text string:
>
> ```
> [left,bottom,width,height]
> ```
>
> If the Units property is data (the default), left and bottom are the
>   x- and y-coordinates of the lower left corner of the text Extent.
>
> For all other values of Units, left and bottom are the distance from
>   the lower left corner of the axes Position rectangle to the lower left
>   corner of the text Extent. width and height are the dimensions of the
>   Extent rectangle. All measurements are in units specified by the Units
>   property.

Comment: called by `get(get(gca,'XLabel'),'Extent')`

Comment: Hi Amro and Rasman, how do I find out if the unit is default (data) or something else? I try the following code figure; xlabel('XXX'); get(get(gca, 'Xlabel'), 'extent'); The opened figure has range of x from 0 to 1, the returned xlabel extent is 0.4617 -0.1092 0.0670  0.0485, the left and top is good, but why the width is only 0.0670? Seems something wrong.

Comment: text objects have a `'Units'` property `hTxt = get(gca,'Xlabel'); get(hTxt,'Units')`. By default it is `data` unless you explicitly specify otherwise

Comment: `0.067` seems reasonable (your plot ranges from 0 to 1, and this width is about half the length between two ticks, which is about right if you look at the plot). Remember it is in data units.. You can always set the units to pixels then again query the extent property to get it in absolute pixel units. Just remember to set it back to 'data units' or it wont be positioned correctly when the figure/axis is resized

Comment: Thanks Amro. I got the idea now. But I found a problem in 3D plot, if I do the following figure; [X, Y, Z]=peaks; surf(X, Y, Z); xlabel('XXXXXXXXXX'); get(get(gca, 'Xlabel'), 'extent'); It shows all zero then, so this won't work on 3D plot?

Comment: @user1285419: yes in 3D plot, the 'extent' property does not make sense (assuming the default **data units**). On the other hand, if you change to pixels units, you can get absolute width/height of bounding box in pixels

Comment: @user1285419: In case this was not clear, quantities in data units are **relative** to the axes limits/size (so in your first 2D example, if you maximize the figure and query the extent property again, it would be different). In 3D, the issue is that the labels are no longer aligned/parallel with the axes, so IMO it makes no sense to express their width/height in terms of the axes, and only **absolute** measures are of importance (like pixels, points, inches, etc..)